# How to use gurobi in pyomo/python in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pyomo, gurobi

I am trying to use Gurobi solver instead of GLPK in google colab, but I'm not managing how to do it. I do not know the code to import and use it in SolverFactory.

I have tried to use the following command lines:

```
!apt-get install -y -qq glpk-utils
#SolverFactory('glpk', executable='/usr/bin/glpsol').solve(model).write()
SolverFactory("gurobi", solver_io="python").solve(model).write()
```

I put a comment in the 'glpk' solver and tried to do the same for the gurobi, but I did not import gurobi or installed something previously. What did I miss? What should I do or what should be the code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `gurobipy` and `pyomo`:

```
!pip install gurobipy pyomo
```

[image]

**Edit**: for larger problem, you have to request a [WLS license](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/4409582394769-Google-Colab-Installation-and-Licensing) (Academic in your case)

After obtained the license, use:

```
# Create an environment with your WLS license
params = {
"WLSACCESSID": 'your wls accessid (string)',
"WLSSECRET": 'your wls secret (string)',
"LICENSEID": <your license id (integer)>,
}
env = gp.Env(params=params)

# Create the model within the Gurobi environment
model = gp.Model(env=env)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked out, but since my problem is too large, it shows the following message:

`GurobiError: Model too large for size-limited license; visit https://www.gurobi.com/free-trial for a full license`
Do you know how can I integrate an academic license into google colab?

Comment: It's not a big deal. Follow the instructions in my answer.

Comment: Hello Corralien, thanks! But I have some difficulties yet. I want to use pyomo constructor, so I do not want to model in gurobi environment, I just want to change glpk to gurobi. In this case, does it work to construct the model in pyomo and use gurobi in solverfactory? (ps.: I'm waiting my WLS license from gurobi.com). I also have a question: "gp.Env" what means gp. ? Which package did you import? Thanks

Comment: `import gurobipy as gp`. It doesn't matter if you use gurobi or not, pyomo does.

Comment: Hello friend, how are you? I have now my WLS license, do you know where can I find my WLSACCESSID and WLSSECRET? I have downloaded the gurobi.lic file, but how can I open it? I wonder how to find these parameters, I just saw my license number in gurobi.com

Comment: Try to generate the license using https://license.gurobi.com/manager/licenses

Comment: Did you solved your problem with WLS license?

Comment: @alex you can use the terminal/gedit (if you are linux user) or any text editor to view gurobi.lic file